# Powershell: How to find out which running services aren't part of OS and non-MS

Tags: powershell, service

Is there a way to find out using Powershell which running services are non-native to Windows ? In other words, services that aren't part Windows OS and are non-Microsoft. I want to find out all the services that were installed by our vendors.
Finding out running services is easy:

`Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}`

Comment: I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head. I can tell you how I would approach it regardless. I would look at the services installed on a fresh build deployed from a template or image or however else you deploy a new system. Then I would do a comparison of the `get-service` output from the new system vs. the system in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do with it **`Get-Service`** alone, because even though the service-info objects it outputs have a **`.BinaryPathName` property, that property is available in PowerShell *Core* only *and* it is not necessarily the true service binary**, which is often a DLL hosted by the generic `svchost.exe` service host.

To find the binary file path in all cases, you **must (also) query the service definitions in the *registry***. Once you have the file path, you can use `Get-Item` and the `.VersionInfo` property of the file-info objects returned to extract information such as the product and company name.

The `Get-ServiceFileInfo` function at the bottom does just that; it allows you to run commands such as:

```
# Return information about all services that aren't part of Windows.
# (May still include Microsoft services).
Get-ServiceFileInfo | Where ProductName -ne 'Microsoft® Windows® Operating System'
```

---

#### `Get-ServiceFileInfo` source code (PSv5+, but could be adapted to work with lower versions):

```
# Note: While it is possible to run without elevated privileges,
#       not all file information is retrievable then.
#requires -runAsAdministrator

function Get-ServiceFileInfo {

  Set-StrictMode -Version 1

  Get-Service | ForEach-Object {

    # PowerShell Core only:
    # Get the service binary path, which may or may not be the true service 
    # executable.
    $binaryPath = $_.BinaryPathName
    
    # Windows PowerShell:
    # We fall back on trying to obtain the "ImagePath" value from the registry.
    # Note: Even in PowerShell Core there appear to be services that Get-Service fails 
    #       to query even when running as admin, such as "SshdBroker"
    #       (a non-terminating error is issued).
    #       Reading from the registry is needed in that case too, 
    #       but, only succeeds when running as admin.
    if (-not $binaryPath) {
      $binaryPath = try { Get-ItemPropertyValue -EA Ignore "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$($_.Name)" ImagePath } catch { }
    }
    
    # Test for svchost.exe, which indicates the need to look for the service-specific DLL path elsewhere.
    if ($binaryPath -like '*\svchost.exe *') {
      # Get the actual binary (DLL) from the registry, subkey "Parameters", value "ServiceDLL"
      # NOTE: Some services exist in *2* (multiple?) incarnations, as "<name>"" and "<name>_<num>"
      #       Only the "<name>" incarnation has the "ServiceDLL" value, so we fall back on that.
      foreach ($keyName in $_.Name, ($_.Name -split '_')[0]) {
        # NOTE: Most DLL-based services store the "ServiceDLL" value in the "Parameters" subkey, but
        #       some have it in the service's root key itself.
        foreach ($subKeyName in "$keyName\Parameters", $keyName) {
          $binaryPath = try { Get-ItemPropertyValue -EA Ignore "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$subKeyName" ServiceDLL } catch { }
          if ($binaryPath) { break }
        }
      }
    }
    
    # Sanitize the path:
    # * Some values have enclosing "...", so we strip them, 
    # * others have arguments, so we only take the first token.
    $binaryPath = if ($binaryPath.StartsWith('"')) {
      ($binaryPath -split '"')[1]
    } else {
      # The path / command line isn't or doesn't start with a double-quoted token, which
      # can mean one of two things:
      #  * It is a command line based on an unquoted executable, possibly with arguments.
      #  * It is a service DLL path - possibly with spaces in the (expanded) path.
      if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $binaryPath -Type Leaf) {
        $binaryPath # Value as a whole is a file path
      } else {
        (-split $binaryPath)[0] # Value is a command line, extract executable
      }
    }

    $FileVersionInfo = if ($binaryPath) { (Get-Item -LiteralPath $binaryPath).VersionInfo }

    # Construct the output object.        
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Name = $_.Name
      BinaryPath = if ($binaryPath) { $binaryPath } else { '(n/a)'; Write-Error "Failed to determine binary path for service '$($_.Name)'. Try running as admin." }
      ProductName = $FileVersionInfo.ProductName
      FileDescription = $FileVersionInfo.FileDescription
      CompanyName = $FileVersionInfo.CompanyName
    }
    
  }

}
```