# Split-Path removes ¨´´ from Service Pathname

Tags: powershell, split, path, scripting

It´s as simple as that `Split-Path` is removing the last '`"`' from every Pathname you query form any service:

```
$service = get-wmiobject -query 'select * from win32_service where name="SQLBrowser"';
Write-output $service.pathname 
Write-output $service.pathname | Split-Path
```

[image]

I tried with a few services and it's always the same.

Do you think this is a PowerShell bug we need to flag to Microsoft?

Is there any workaround?

**EDIT:** Thank you @mklement0 for the reply and the workaround.

It turns out this was indeed a [Microsotf PowerShell bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3759#issuecomment-467175579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`.PathName` property of the `Win32_Service` instances** returned by your `Get-WmiObject` call:

- **sometimes contains values with *embedded* double quotes** around the executable path

  - Such embedded double quotes aren't part of the path and must be *removed* before further processing, such as via `Split-Path`.
- **may additionally contain *arguments*** to pass to the executable, whether the latter is double-quoted or not.

Caveat: Some `Win32_Service` instances return `$null` in their `.PathName` property.

To deal with both scenarios, use the following approach:

```
$service = get-wmiobject -query 'select * from win32_service where name="SQLBrowser"'

$serviceBinaryPath = if ($service.pathname -like '"*') { 
                       ($service.pathname -split '"')[1] # get path without quotes
                     } else {
                       (-split $service.pathname)[0] # get 1st token
                     }

# Assuming that $serviceBinaryPath is non-null / non-empty, 
# it's safe to apply `Split-Path` to it now.
```

Do note that quite a few services use the generic `svchost.exe` executable, so the `.PathName` value doesn't necessarily reflect the service's specific binary - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774884/45375).

As an aside: `Get-WmiObject` was deprecated in PowerShell v3 in favor of `Get-CimInstance` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).